# What is a projective rational function in Fulton's book?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-curves

I'm reading [Fulton's algebraic curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and I don't know if I understood correctly this definition on the page 46:

[image]

What does the author mean by $f,g\in \Gamma_h(V)$ being of the same degree? Since
$f$ and $g$ are equivalence classes of $\Gamma_h(V)$ we can write $f=f'+I(V)$ and $g=g'+I(V)$, where $f',g'\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_{n+1}]$. So, is he saying that $f'$ and $g'$ are forms of the same degree?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it means that **for some choice** of $f',g' \; (g'\notin I(V))$ these forms have same degree.